# Android Drive GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The specified account could not be signed in

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I need to use the drive api to create a file with some content from my app, so I followed the "Getting Started" section from Drive api web page.

So I  enabled the api on my developer´s console, created an OAuth client id as it says. **(Can I use the api if I haven´t paid the 2$5 yet?)**

On my settings activity on the onCreate method I'm doing:

```
 googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

I'm implementing the methods:

```
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    getGoogleApiClient().disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, resolvingError);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (resolvingError) {
        // Already attempting to resolve an error.
        return;
    }else if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            resolvingError = true;
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            getGoogleApiClient().connect();
        }
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        resolvingError = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        resolvingError = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(!getGoogleApiClient().isConnecting() && !getGoogleApiClient().isConnected()){
                getGoogleApiClient().connect();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Success!!! :D :D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}
```

Then I call **googleApiClient.connect();** on a button onclick method.

I'm getting the select account google drive dialog, select an account and press OK, and I'm getting this error on the connection result:

> **E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The specified account could not be signed in.**

I searched over the web and cant find the cause of this problem.... maybe I'm doing something wrong on the developers's console... don't know...

**UPDATE:**

So i delete the project on Google developer´s console and create it again, i also add the Drive Api and enable it, i added a product name on authorization screen, and a new client id with my package name and sha1 id...

also update my manifest,

added to manifest tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

to application tag:

```
<meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

to the activity tag where im doing the connection:

```
<meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID"
       android:value="id=<app id i took this id from developers´console>" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
<data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.<app id>" />
```

i also building a signed apk using the debug keystore to test my app. (on real device).

after all this the error is still rising...

Comment: `can i use the api if i haven´t pay the 25$ yet` - this payment matters for app publishing, not API usage

Comment: Is your Google Play Services up to date?

Comment: My _guess_ is that there is a problem with the setup you did at the Developer's Console.  [This discussion](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170487) may be helpful.

Comment: My Goggle Play Services sdk is up to date, i also checked the recomended discussion, and i found i was missing some permissions at my manifest, also make a signed apk to test my app again, but the same error is rising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My guess is that there is a problem with the setup you did at the Developer's Console. This discussion may be helpful. –  qbix

hello, reading the discussion qbix mention above i just found the cause of my problem...

the default flavor at my project structure had an incorrect Application id, i just change it to my app package "com.xxxxx.yyyyy".

so i beleave when googleApiClient attempted to connect, find diferent package name at id client credencials and deny access....

now is working fine thanx....

Comment: where can i change the application ID?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my usual checklist:

1/ get the APK in question, push it through an unzipper, like 7-zip. you'll find a folder META-INF with a file CERT.RSA. Get it.

2/ run '**keytool -printcert -file ......\CERT.RSA**' and copy/save the SHA1  '**11.22.33...99**'

3/ get you package name (from manifest?)   '**com.blabla.yourproject**'

4/ open developers console 'https://console.developers.google.com/project'

5/ in your project, check:

- Enabled APIs:   drive API
- Credentials:  Package name: '**com.blabla.yourproject**', Fingerprint: '**11.22.33...99**'
- Consent Screen:  Email: yourmail@gmail.com , Product Name:  'YourProject'

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Pleas try to First normal Google account Login

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).
addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.addApi(Plus.API)
.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
//.addApi(Drive.API)
//.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case cause was in incorrect 'package name' in OATH client settings:
was: com.blabla.prog
correct one: bla.bla.com.prog

Comment: You're not adding clarity to the issue by an answer like this. The package name format is clearly defined in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

try to ignore the API connection by doing this:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApiIfAvailable(Drive.API)
```

I've done in this way and everything seems working. I really don't know why, i suppose that the Driver.API creates some problems, and doing in this way you can use the maps,the markers and all that stuff. I know that is not a good answer because i don't provide you a correct explanation, but anyway, it can help.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error may occur in following situations:

1. If you have used **release key SHA1 signing-certificate fingerprint** while creating Oauth 2.0 client ID and running your application **without signing it with release key** (i.e. running with debug key). This is also true for debug key.
2. If you have used different package name while creating Oauth 2.0 client ID

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can go wrong is that you create credentials for "API Key" instead of "OAuth 2.0 client ID".

Yeah silly I know.. guide says "Client ID" so I guess I went by the length of the string :)