# Android Google Drive access

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to access my Goodle Drive account from android app on Emulator.
I followed all on : https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth
regarding **Authorizing Android Apps**
But still I cannot authorize my self.
So, **OAuth** is created on the developper console, **Public API access**
 is created too.
But still I get :

```
08-04 13:09:22.154    1683-1711/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSActivity﹕ gms.StatusHelper Status from wire: INVALID_KEY status: null
08-04 13:09:22.154    1683-1711/com.google.process.gapps I/GLSUser﹕ GLS error: INVALID_KEY my_mail@gmail.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
08-04 13:09:22.160    1664-2522/com.google.android.gms E/ClientConnectionOperation﹕ Handling authorization failure
    com.google.android.gms.drive.auth.c: Authorization failed: See https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth for details on authorizing an application.
```

Also, I put permission:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Just as

```
   <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID"
                android:value="329914295769-9e34odtlolkc6sqavaj5uqrduik1ouml.apps.googleusercontent.com" />

        </activity>
```

But still I cannot authmenticate my self when I try:

```
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
//                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .setAccountName("erakovic.boban@gmail.com")
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

where **mGoogleApiClient** is GoogleApiClient instance.
I googled all morning, tried all I could do, but still nothing.
I am just wondering why **Certificate fingerprint (SHA1)**, since application is on Emulator run, so actually, we do not sign it before start process of generation of signed APK.

What do I doing wrong, I do not get ?

Thanks

Comment: just u think google drive also required play store lib but in emulator there is not any play store so why you are not try it on real device

Comment: Is that mean, debugging google drive via emulator is NOT possible?

Comment: is there any play store in emulator

Comment: There are Google Play Services, which I installed. So, there are libs, I can use all classes and invoke mentods, but as you can see from my response, there is still an authorization issue.

Comment: To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:

A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

Comment: I actually using Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs 21/22, Lolipop 5.0.1

Comment: First, I've never managed to make the emulator work,since I could not get the GooPlaySvcs to update. The GooPlaySvcs check (GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) would fail before even getting to the 'GoogleApiClient.Builder'. So I quit the emulator. With the real device, I use the 'last-ditch-check' desctibed in [SO 31252524](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252524/android-drive-googleplayservicesutil-the-specified-account-could-not-be-signed/31525197#31525197), basically double-check the APK file against the developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging do not use Certificate fingerprint (SHA1) from keystore for creating signed App by if you create API key at DeveloperConsole.
For unsigned App ( from Eclipse instaled direct to device, emulator... ) have to use fingerprint (SHA1) from debug.keystore.

The default storage location debug.keystore file is in ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux, in C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP, and in C:\Users\.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

You can obtain SHA1 from debug.keystore with keytool command
keytool -list -keystore debug.keystore

The keytool default location is c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\

Comment: I am using android studio, not eclipse. What would be in that case debugging keystore ?

Comment: I don't know where you can see debug.keystore at AndroidStudio. Try keytool. Watch above.

Comment: Thanks guys, that actually worked. Just creation of new Client Id, with this debug.keystore SHA1, without any meta-data in the manifest, and that's it. For debuging in Emulator, at least. Thanx